# C# Win. Form : Adding a line break to a richtextbox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, rtf

I have a richtextbox in which i am filling with formatted text. The **RTF of richtextbox** looks like this:-

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Bookman Old Style;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1033\b\f0\fs21 Name\b0\tab : John Miller\par
\b Current Address\b0\tab : ABCDEFGHI JKLMNOP QRST UVWXYZ\par
\b Permanent Address\b0\tab : ABCDEFGHI JKLMNOP QRST UVWXYZ\par
\b Temporary Address\b0\tab : ABCDEFGHI JKLMNOP QRST UVWXYZ\par
}
```

and the **OUTPUT** of it looks like this:-

---

**Name**    : John Miller
**Current Address**     : ABCDEFGHI JKLMNOP QRST UVWXYZ
**Permanent Address**   : ABCDEFGHI JKLMNOP QRST *'line break to be added here'* UVWXYZ
**Temporary Address**   : ABCDEFGHI JKLMNOP QRST UVWXYZ

---

Now i want to add a line break at **text index 119** where ***line break to be added here*** is written. How do i do it?

### Challanges

1. You cannot directly use linebreak in text like:

   `richTextBox.Text = richTextBox.Text.Substring(0,119) + Environment.NewLine + richTextBox.Text.Substring(119, richTextBox.Text.Length - 119);`

   because it will **remove the bold settings** i have done in text text.
2. cannot change **directly in RTF** as we dont know at what index that particular text might be at. Suppose the **text is at 119 index** but the **RTF is at 263th index**. 
   We also cant use text search to find the index in RTF as all the 3 addresses are exactly the same.

Comment: Well then, exactly what mechanism are you using to determine where the line break needs to be?

Comment: System.Magic.DoMagic<SomeSpecialMagic>(myMagicValue);  Seriously though, The only other option is to modify where you actually create the text in the textbox, which you haven't included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
rtb1.SelectionStart = 119;
rtb1.SelectionLength = 0;
rtb1.SelectedText = Environment.NewLine;
```